# Git deploy hook not deleting deleted files

Tags: git

Guys i use git to deploy changes to the live server.

Set up is bare repository outside of html folder with with following hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html git checkout -f
```

It updates changed files and creates new files, but it does not delete the deleted files.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the end:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html git clean -df
```

The `git clean` command is used to remove untracked files from a working directory; `-f` is required for it to do anything, and `-d` will make it remove untracked directories as well rather than leaving them empty.

Comment: I will add that this is not necessary *if* the index in your bare repository corresponds to the assigned (via `--git-work-tree` or `GIT_WORK_TREE`) work-tree. If the index in your bare repository corresponds to some *other* work-tree, you will be in danger of not having changed files updated, in some (rare) cases.

Comment: @torek, could you explain a little bit more about that? I am new to git.

How to check if the index in my bare repository corresponds to the assigned work-tree?

Comment: @Amber, will it remove all files in working directory that are not present in local repository i am pushing from. Or only files that were deleted in local repository and are mentioned in commits as deleted? I am looking to achieve the 2nd. Cause some folders are not present in remote repo by design.

Comment: @MployBy: it's a bit complicated to describe, until you're familiar with how the index works with a regular (non-bare) repository. One way to compare the index to your special work-tree, though, is to use `git --work-tree=<path> status` from the bare repository directory. If they match, the status will show "nothing to commit, working directory clean". Or you can view the index contents directly with `git ls-files --debug --stage`.

Comment: @MployBy put the things you don't want to be removed in a `.gitignore` file.